# Update image in php

Tags: php, html, css

I want to make an update account page. When I change the image and press update it runs correctly, but when I update any other field than image, the image is deleted from the browser and also from the database table.
This is my code:

```
<?php       
include("includes/db.php");
    $user=$_SESSION['customer_email'];

    $get_customer="select * from costumers where customer_email='$user'"; 
    $run_customer=mysqli_query($con, $get_customer);
    $row_customer=mysqli_fetch_array($run_customer);

    $c_id=$row_customer['customer_id'];
    $name=$row_customer['customer_name'];
    $email=$row_customer['customer_email'];
    $pass=$row_customer['customer_pass'];
    $img=$row_customer['customer_image'];    
?>       

<div style="margin-left:15%; margin-top:10%">
  <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  />
     <table width="500px" align="center" bgcolor="blueskay">
        <tr align="center">
           <td colspan="2"><h2>Update Your Account</h2></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Customer Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="c_name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" required /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
             <td align="right">Customer Image:</td>
             <td><input type="file" name="c_image" value="<?php echo $img; ?>"  /><img src="customer_images/<?php echo $img; ?>" width="150px" height="100px"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
             <td align="right">Customer Email:</td>
             <td><input type="text" name="c_email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>"required /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
             <td align="right">Customer Password:</td>
             <td><input type="password" name="c_pass" value="<?php echo $pass; ?>" required /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr align="center">
             <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="update" value="Update Account"/></td>
             <td></td>
        </tr> 
     </table>
   </form>
</div>
```

And this my php code:

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['update'])){

    $customer_id=$c_id;
    $c_name= $_POST['c_name'];
    $c_email= $_POST['c_email'];
    $c_pass= $_POST['c_pass'];
    $c_image= $_FILES['c_image']['name'];
    $c_image_temp=$_FILES['c_image']['tmp_name'];

    move_uploaded_file($c_image_temp , "customer_images/$c_image");

        $c_update="update costumers set customer_name='$c_name', customer_email='$c_email', customer_pass='$c_pass',  customer_image= '$c_image'
         where customer_id='$customer_id'";

    $run_update=mysqli_query($con, $c_update);

    if($run_update){

        echo"<script>alert('Your Account has been Updated successfully, Thanks')</script>";
                echo"<script>window.open('my_account.php','_self')</script>";   
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: You need to update each item with discretion *or* you need to populate all of the database values in your form so that when submitted it only changes the portion of the form that was actually changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to check whether the image is empty or not and update by condition.

```
$customer_id=$c_id;
$c_name= $_POST['c_name'];
$c_email= $_POST['c_email'];
$c_pass= $_POST['c_pass'];
$c_image= $_FILES['c_image']['name'];
$c_image_temp=$_FILES['c_image']['tmp_name'];

if($c_image_temp != "")
{
    move_uploaded_file($c_image_temp , "customer_images/$c_image");
    $c_update="update costumers set customer_name='$c_name', customer_email='$c_email', customer_pass='$c_pass',  customer_image= '$c_image'
     where customer_id='$customer_id'";   
}else
{
    $c_update="update costumers set customer_name='$c_name', customer_email='$c_email', customer_pass='$c_pass'
     where customer_id='$customer_id'";
}

$run_update=mysqli_query($con, $c_update);
```

Answer (score 0):

Update data and image in database:

```
<?php
include('db.php');
$id=$_GET['id'];
$sql = "select * from `bio` where id='".$id."'"; 
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
?>

<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <form method='post' action="Update.php?id=<?php echo $row[0];?>" enctype="multipart/form-data"> <!-- getting id -->
        <input type='hidden' name='id' value="<?php echo $row[0];?>"><br><br>
            name: <input type='text' name='name' value="<?php echo $row[1];?>"><br><br>
            fathersname: <input type='text' name='fathersname' value="<?php echo $row[2];?>"><br><br>
            mailid: <input type='email' name='mailid' value="<?php echo $row[3];?>"><br><br>
            dob: <input type='Date'name='dob' value="<?php echo $row[4];?>"><br><br>
            phoneno: <input type='text'name='phoneno' value="<?php echo $row[5];?>"><br><br>
    
        Upload image: <input type='file' name='res' value=""><br><br> 
        <img src="upload/<?php echo $row[6]?>" style="width:100px;height:100">
        <input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'>
    </form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $id=$_POST['id'];   
    $n=$_POST['name'];
    $f=$_POST['fathersname'];
    $m=$_POST['mailid'];
    $d=$_POST['dob'];
    $p=$_POST['phoneno'];
    $i=$_FILES['res']['name'];
    $target_dir = "upload/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["res"]["name"]);
    $FileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["res"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) 
    {
        $sql="Update `bio` set name='$n',fathersname='$f',mailid='$m',dob='$d',phoneno='$p',uploadimage='$i' where id='".$id."'";
        if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
        {
            header('location:view.php');
        }
        else 
        {
            echo 'not updated';
        }
    }
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for having a go at helping out.
However, your answer does still include SQL injection, XSS, and doesn't fully correct the issue.